# How to get the price of a stock at a particular date from Google Finance?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I want to get the price of a particular stock at a particular date in Google Sheets using the Google Finance forumula.

I tried this formula:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",12/13/2013)
```

But it didn't work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Just surround the date by quotation marks:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/13/2013")
```

Also, if you want only the number, wrap it in INDEX formula

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/13/2013"),2,2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to deal with the Saturday and Sunday prices?

Comment: Unfortunately Google has their finance head so far up their ass, these formulas no longer work anymore.  Gotta use =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",date(2015,12,13)),2,2) like TechySoul points out.

Comment: Date needs to be UNquoted: `Error`
`Function QUOTE parameter 3 expects number values. But '12/13/2013' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.` [Fixed]

Comment: @TomHale, dates need to be quoted. 12/13/2013 means 12 divided by 13 divided by 2013. You are probably getting this error because your spreadsheet expects dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Comment: can someone please check if this works for them: ```=GOOGLEFINANCE("SOX","price", "12/29/2023")```

Answer (score 34):

This API has undergone some changes and the updated solution that now works is like this -

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",date(2015,12,13)),2,2)
```

For more updates on the Google Finance API to be used in Google Docs please refer [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB&rd=1)

Comment: They also recommend avoiding "GOOG" and prefering "NASDAQ:GOOG" for disambiguation. :)

Comment: For today's price, =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",TODAY()),2,2) is not working.

Answer (score 9):

## Update August 2022

I have tried several of the solutions here and none of them worked for me. After a while I noticed that all the solutions use "**,**" as the separator but for me it must be "**;**" for some reason.

What worked for me is the following:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CHFEUR"; "price"; "22.06.2021");2;2)
```

*This fetches the exchange price from CHF to EUR on 22.06.2021 and gives you back only the numeric value of the price (hence, the INDEX function wrapping around).*

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Can't edit right now, but there is a quote missing "22.06.2021 -> "22.06.2021"  AND if you copy this and add the quote, you still get an error, only as reference date field it worked for me @l-butz

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CHFEUR"; "price"; DATE(2014;1;1););2;2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?